# jar files not installing in the local repo in the m2 folder using maven install

Tags: java, maven

I have a child project which is being consumed by the parent project.I need to test something in child so not creating a release version inplace I am trying to install the child project jar file into local repo so that I can use it in my parent project.

Now I am facing 2 problems:

1. When doing mvn install I am getting errors related to the code used in the project.These errors are not seen while compiling.
2. in my local .m2 repo directory the jar files are missing for the child project hence errors are seen in the parent project as the dependency is missing.

Please help me in navigating the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: "I have a child project which is being consumed by the parent project.". Hum, what? Could you post a sample of your POM? I don't understand. Post your error message also. And, tell explicitely what it is you want to do here. I feel there is something _very_ wrong.

Comment: If a child need the artifact of the parent, and the parent can only be built if al child-modules are finished, it is a circle. This structure is impossible to build.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix the errors that you get while doing mvn install in child project.
Once errors are fixed your jar will get deployed in your local .m2 repository and would be accessible by parent project.